# WPF triggers affecting values set in code, not XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, effects

In my app I have toggle buttons that have three possible states; "Unchecked", "Checked", and "Previously Used". When the user comes to this particular screen, some of the toggle buttons will be in the "Previously Used" state to show what work has been done. Clicking on a toggle button (no matter the current state) will place it into the "Checked" state. Only one of these toggle buttons can be checked at a time. The different states are indicated by different colored outer glow, or no glow at all.

To set the outer glow for the "Checked" state I use a trigger on IsChecked euqals true.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">                          
      <Setter Property="Effect">
         <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Salmon" BlurRadius="40" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1.0"></DropShadowEffect>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Trigger>                        
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

For the "Previously Used" state I apply the outer glow in code, not markup. I have to do this because determining if the button should be in this state is done by checking values in a List.

```
if (mExistingViews.Contains(mViews[i].LocalizedName))
{
   DropShadowEffect dse = new DropShadowEffect();
   dse.ShadowDepth = 0;
   dse.BlurRadius = 20;
   dse.Opacity = 1.0;
   dse.Color = Colors.Yellow;
   mViewButtons[i].Effect = dse;
}
```

However, when a toggle button is clicked when in the "Previously Used" state, the trigger doesn't seem to have any effect. The outer glow does not change.

What am I doing wrong? Will a trigger not effect something that has not been set in XAML?

Comment: When does your code that sets the effect is run? I suspect what happens is that your trigger gets applied, and then your code runs and overwrites the effect.

Comment: My code runs when the screen is first brought into view. The triggers only gets applied when the user clicks on one of the buttons. So it shouldn't be the case that the trigger is getting overwritten.

Comment: @Dan: Pavel means your `ControlTemplate` trigger is being overwritten. A better word would be suppressed. Setting the `Effect` in code is setting a local value. Read this: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set the `DropShadowEffect` on the `Button`, you are setting the local value of the `Button`'s `Effect` property, which is a `DependencyProperty` (`Button.EffectProperty`). The local value overrides any other possible value until it is cleared like this:

```
button1.ClearValue( Button.EffectProperty );
```

However, that just makes the workings a bit more convoluted, because you also have to make sure you clear it if was set before and hasn't been cleared yet.

Instead, you could create an AttachedProperty `PreviouslyUsed` to put on the `ToggleButton`s and use `Bindings` so they get their value a bit more automagically. Then refer to this AttachedProperty value in your triggers and you'll have one drop shadow for `PreviouslyUsed`, and another for `IsChecked`.

The part you'll have to wire up is the binding, and you'll probably have to use an `IValueConverter` somewhere to turn `mViews[i].LocalizedName` into a `true` or `false` for `PreviouslyUsed`.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about your setup with `mViews` and such to offer more advice about that. I don't know whether your `ToggleButtons` are part of databinding or not. I suspect that they are not, as you seem to be iterating an array of them. If you bound your `mViews` objects to the `ItemsSource` of a `ListBox`, for example, you could create a `DataTemplate` that generates the `ToggleButtons` with the AttachedProperty already in place. That would also simplify your `IsChecked` situation by binding it to whether or not that item is selected in the `ListBox`, and then the `ListBox` takes care of making sure that only one is selected.